# Kubernetes V2 provider to build application docker image and deploy using manifest

Tags: spinnaker

Can someone please let me know how to build docker image and deploy using Deploy(Manifest) in Kubernetes V2 Provider?

**Spinnaker Version :** 1.6.1
**Provider :** Kubernetes V2 (Manifest from artifact)

Answer (score 0):

Building the image is not a primary concern of Spinnaker, and you can accomplish that in a number of ways, from local `docker build`s to managed services like [Google Container Builder](https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/).

As for deploying using manifest in Spinnaker, can you share what you'd like to accomplish (e.g. deploy a k8s manifest residing in github), and where specifically you're having issues? Have you tried the steps on [this page](https://www.spinnaker.io/guides/user/kubernetes-v2/deploy-manifest/), starting with copying and pasting the manifest contents in the UI?